# Get kendo datasource independent of widget

Tags: kendo-ui

From a grid I can get the data source using:

```
var ds = $(#mygrid).data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
```

or from a listview:

```
var ds = $(#mylist).data("kendoListView").dataSource;
```

But how do I get it if I do not know if its a grid or listview (or scheduler)?

For example:

```
// Refresh data for any dataSource based control:
$(#myControl).data("???").dataSource.read();
```

Comment: where (in which event) do you need to call `$(#myControl).data("???").dataSource.read();`? do you use a wrapper like MVC or PHP or just client side pure javascript and html? how you define your dataSource?

Comment: Just javascript (+jQuery) client side code.

Comment: how you define your dataSource? and in which event do you need to call `$(#myControl).data("???").dataSource.read();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the widget of an object like this:

```
var control = kendo.widgetInstance($('#myControl'), kendo.ui);
```

Then you could check if there is a dataSource, and do something with it:

```
if(control.dataSource) {
    control.dataSource.read();
}
```